# How do you "reference" a particular turtle within as ask turtles block?

Tags: netlogo

Whenever we use the "ask" command for all agents of a particular kind or breed, the Netlogo program goes through each agent one by one in random order. What I want is really simple: **I would like to access the turtle whose turn it is at that moment**.

I can't seem to find an appropriate command for this.

My code for reference purposes is as follows:

```
to surfer-visits-source
  ask surfers [
    if ([quality] of one-of [out-link-st-neighbors] of one-of out-link-ss-neighbors) < expected-quality
    [
      let temp ([who] of out-link-ss-neighbors)
      create-link-ss-to one-of sources with [who != temp]
      ask links-ss with [end1 = [who] of surfer][
        ask links-ss with [[who] of turtle temp] [
       die
       ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the question: what do you mean with "access" the turtle? What do you intend to do with that turtle?
In general terms, `self` always refers to the agent that is executing that command.
A statement like `ask turtle 0 [ask turtle 1 [print self]]` will print `turtle 1`.

Comment: @Matteo: it was "self" that I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, I see, good!

Answer (score 1):

We can use the ***self*** command to do this.